# How order posts from category by date and comment count?

Tags: wp-query, categories, order

Just like in topic I try to order posts from category by date and comment_count but code below doesn't work:

```
<?php

//get post from current category
$category       = get_the_category();
$category_ID    = $category[0]->term_id;
$args = array(
    'cat'               => $category_ID,
    //limit posts to 3
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
    //order post by date and comments
    'orderby' => array(
        'date'          => 'DESC',
        'comment_count' => 'DESC',
    ),

);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Posts are ordered only by date

Comment: Can you be more specific by posting comment count and post date for all those three posts with their order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you currently have will order the posts by their `post_date` property, which is an SQL column of the type `datetime`. This type stores the date, but also the time (hours, minutes and seconds). The second sorting option, `comment_count`, is only applied to posts with the same timestamp, i.e. that were posted at the exact same second in time.

So, the solution to your problem is to sort by post *date* instead of *datetime*. To do so, you can filter the `orderby` query part in `WP_Query` using the filter [`posts_orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby). With this filter, you can replace the SQL `ORDER` clauses to use the day instead of the datetime.

The code below does this: it adds a function to the filter `posts_orderby` which replaces the `{$wpdb->posts}.post_date` (e.g. `wp_posts.post_date`) by `CAST({$wpdb->posts}.post_date AS DATE)`, which casts the datetime field to `YYYY-MM-DD` format. After executing the query, it removes the filter, ensuring that other queries are not affected.

```
function wpse222104_query_orderby_day( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return str_replace( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_date", "CAST({$wpdb->posts}.post_date AS DATE)", $orderby );
}

// Add the filter to change the ORDER clause
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse222104_query_orderby_day', 10, 2 );

// Run the query with the filters
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Remove the filter
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse222104_query_orderby_day' );
```

This assumes the same `$args` that you already had: there was nothing wrong with them.

### Testing the code

Testing the code shows that the `ORDER BY` clause is correctly changed: the original clause was

```
wp_posts.post_date DESC, wp_posts.comment_count DESC
```

whereas the new one is

```
CAST(wp_posts.post_date AS DATE) DESC, wp_posts.comment_count DESC
```

### Example

The precise time the post was published will now not be considered in sorting: only the date it was posted will. For example, consider the following posts:

```
Title           Date                    Comment count
Example Post    2014-12-16 10:12:16     6
Another one     2014-12-16 21:50:07     4
Yet Another     2012-08-02 11:15:20     25
```

Here, your original query would return the posts in the order

1. Another one
2. Example post
3. Yet another

Whereas the new code would return the posts in order

1. Example post
2. Another one
3. Yet another

as "Example post" and "Another one" were posted on the same day, but "Example post" has more comments.

Comment: OK thanks. So this can't be done by order closure because I need the newest posts ordered by comments count too.

Comment: It orders posts by day, first, and if two or more posts share the same publish date, they are ordered by comment count. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly what I expected but your answer help me a lot. In my situation I need to get newests posts and this posts have to be sorted by comment count (most commented post in top). Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using pre-4.x version of WordPress. Older version does not support `array()` as `orderby` value. Use `'orderby' => 'date comment_count'` instead:

```
<?php
$category       = get_the_category();
$category_ID    = $category[0]->term_id;
$args = array(
    'cat'                 => $category_ID,
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'orderby'             => 'date comment_count', // date is primary
    'order'               => 'DESC' // not required because it's the default value
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```